# AppDomain.Unload memory leak

Tags: .net, memory-leaks, appdomain

I have a similar issue in my AppDomain to what is being described in this post

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/clr/thread/20de15d6-3111-4c2e-a04b-feb341a67ebc

Can anybody elaborate on the solution, maybe with an example, as i urgently need this fix but the answer seems slightly confusing to me.

```
{
    AppDomain domain2 = AppDomain.CreateDomain("ADFHelper");  
    obj = domain2.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap ("Econ.Test", "Econ.Test.ADFHelper"); 
    object results = obj.GetType().InvokeMember("DoADFTest",System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Type.DefaultBinder, obj, new object[] {     ResArray.ToArray() }); 
    AppDomain.Unload(domain2);
}
```

Comment: -1 for forcing us to go to another site and for mentioning urgency.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the thread was incorrectly using `AppDomain.Load` to try to load the assembly in a new domain.  What this actually did was essentially load the assembly in the **current** domain.  As [the documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36az8x58.aspx) states (emphasis added):

> **This method should be used only to load an assembly into the current
>   application domain.** This method is provided as a convenience for
>   interoperability callers who cannot call the static Assembly.Load
>   method. **To load assemblies into other application domains, use a
>   method such as CreateInstanceAndUnwrap.**

The solution is as described in that documentation -- use something like [`AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c4f1xde.aspx) to load a class in the new app domain.  This would be the right approach if the class you are loading is a [`MarshalByRefObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject.aspx) and you need to call methods on it from inside the current app domain.

If you don't want a `MarshalByRefObject` and don't really need to touch the newly loaded class (i.e. you just want the type to be loaded and "left alone" in the new app domain), you could do with [`AppDomain.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44s54yc4.aspx) instead which doesn't require marshalling or remoting.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I have implemented my code as you suggested, it now looks like the code shown in my edit above

Comment: I keep getting memory leaks. Can you spot anything wrong with my code shown above? thanks again

Comment: Yes, you are triggering a load of the type in your current app domain by using reflection to invoke a member on the instance.  You need to come up with an approach that **completely avoids loading the assembly in your original domain**, perhaps by defining an interface in a common assembly that defines the method(s) you need to call.  To summarize: the target class should be `MarshalByRefObject`, it should implement a common interface, the return type of the methods should be completely serializable data types (primitives or another known common type in a common assembly).

Comment: Thanks again. I now have my server class defined as you recommend: public class ADFHelper : MarshalByRefObject, IADFHelper Please can you tell me what i finally need to do to the Client side of my code to get this working. I have added the common interface as recommended to the client also.

Comment: Your server class should not be `[Serializable]` if it is `MarshalByRefObject`.  The return types for methods in IADFHelper should be `[Serializable]`.

Comment: ahh okay i've changed this now

Comment: From the client, cast the result of `CreateInstanceAndUnwrap` to `IADFHelper` and now make method calls on that interface as usual. Remember that each call you make is a cross-appdomain remoting call and thus quite a bit more expensive than a usual method call. In these cases it is best to use "chunky" (as opposed to "chatty") interfaces.

Comment: Unfortunatley this still has a memory leak! When i comment out the line of code that does a call to the RemotingService the memory leak issue dissapears. This seems very starnge, only thing i can imagine is the AppDomain.Unload(domain2) is not working :-/  Or it could be the fact that the assembley still loads itself into the default appDomain

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6096/discussion-between-bobbymcr-and-caa)

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a coded example, as it is the concept that causes the problem, not the code.

Principally, if you load an Assembly into another AppDomain, it will also be loaded into the current AppDomain - this is necessary to be able to access the types in it and thus do something with it. So on AppDomain.Unload() the Assembly will still be loaded into your calling AppDomain.

You can get around this by using AppDomain.CreateInstanceFrom Method as explained in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2xkww633%28v=VS.90%29.aspx, so you have 2 ways to avoid the problem:

- Use Reflection
- Use an interface to access the new object in the other AppDomain - this interface must be known to both AppDomains, typically you would achieve this by loading a small assembly, that contains the interface, in both AppDomains.